# Is possible to declare something like lambda function what OK button from UIAlert is going to do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, objective-c-blocks

In controller on different actions I need to show `UIAlertView` with "OK" and "CANCEL" buttons, and every "OK" click on those 5 `UIAlertView`s need to do different things. Is possible to declare something like lambda function to specify what "OK" button from each `UIAlertView` is going to do? (In code on 5 places I have with different questions and messages and actions on ok, some don't have text for input at all)

```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Apply"
                          message:@"Are you sure you want to apply ?"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",
                          nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
```

(At the moment I remember action which cause `UIAlertView` to show and then based on action I do different things, but it is not clear code).

Comment: related: [Attaching an object to a UIActionSheet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12763066)

Answer (score 1):

Use a category called [UIKitCategoryAdditions](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/UIKitCategoryAdditions) that implements a block-based `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` for the selection or cancel actions.

It makes it super simple to assign actions to many user prompts without having to implement the delegate methods and deal with handling more than one object's delegate response in the same controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but by extending the existing controls. I would recommend using [RIButtonItem](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks), I'm using it myself in the latest couple of my projects.

Answer (score -1):

Use an objective-c block in lieu of your delegate.

```
delegate: ^(UIAlertView * alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) { doSomethingHere; };
```

Comment: You can't just pass a Block for the delegate argument; the alert view will try to send a message to the Block and you'll get an exception and crash.